# Tensorflow image shape ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have an image and I'd like to do some predictions using a pretrained model. I've prepared my model and everything looks fine in theory but when I use "model.predict(image)" Firstly, these are my codes:

```
import cv2 
import tensorflow as tf

img_array = cv2.imread("hamburger.jpg") #importing image to project

img_array = tf.cast(img_array, tf.int32) / 255 

image = tf.image.resize(img_array, (513, 513)) #reshaping image to make it's shape like (513, 513,3)
```

Everything looks fine as here but when I try to make prediction, I'm getting this error.

```
ValueError: The argument 'images' (value Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 513, 3), dtype=float32)) is not compatible with the shape this function was traced with. Expected shape (None, 513, 513, 3), but got shape (None, 513, 3).
```

I first time saw a shape like (None, 513, 513, 3). How can I do this with my image or should I make my image like it.

Answer (score 0):

To predict a single image with model.predict you need to add a dimension for batch size. To do that use

```
image=np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
```

Comment: Sir I tried it but it's shape looks (1, 513, 513, 3) right now. I guess it's still not like (None, 513, 513, 3)

Comment: That is the shape it should be to predict a single image